# How to increase the rotation of a quaternion by a percentage of X % in a Unity script?

Tags: quaternion, unityscript

There is a simple way to increase the rotation described by a quaternion by a percentage X?

Sorry, but in the documentation of Unity3D I found nothing and I have a poor knowledge on the topic.

Comment: Did you look at Quaternion.Slerp?

Comment: Yes, I read... but if I want a percentage of X > 100%? For example 1000 %

Comment: I'm pretty sure that last parameter is the percentage to rotate towards the target rotation. So if you have a value greater than 100% then it will instantaneously rotate to the target. If you want values greater than 100% then you'll probably need to keep a variable that keeps track of the total rotation and keep updating as each 100% threshold is exceeded, but I'm not really sure that rotating greater than 100% even makes sense. You should recalculate your target destination and rotate to that instead of passing a value greater than 100%.

Answer (score 1):

unless I'm mistaken you want 1+x/100 of a quaternion

```
quat*slerp(quaternion(), quat, X/100)
```

doing a slerp between the null quaternion and the target lets you get the power of a quaternion.

or you can acos the w component and then multiplying with the `fact = 1+x/100` factor and then get `quaternion(cos(acos_w*fact), sin(acos_w*fact)*normalized(quat.xyz))`

if you don't need massive accuracy then you can replace the slerp in the first solution with a lerp